# duplicating page templates

Tags: php, page-template

I am not much of a coder other than basic html and css lol so I have spent days trying to find a solution to this....
an old developer had created custom page templates for this website that call certain filters for the products etc. and this template is applied on 5 pages with different content that is pulled based on 'terms'. The issue is it has a button link that goes to a certain Calendly booking page. So ALL 5 pages have the same buttons that go to that specific booking page. Ideally I want each of those 5 wordpress pages to go to a different corresponding Calendly booking page, so I thought I could duplicate the page template (calling the new one something else) and just change the link in that new template.
Problem I'm having is, it is still pulling the original template when I go into page source and look.

Is anyone able to help me accomplish this please and thank you!!!
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If possible, share your custom page template code.

Answer (score 0):

When you duplicated the template, I assume that you gave the template file a new file name, and placed it in the same directory as the source. And that you changed the "Template Name" in the duplicated file. And then made changes to the new template file to change the code on the button to point to the desired page.

And then you can edit the page and specify the new template for that page.

And that you did this on a Child Theme, because a theme update will overwrite any changes you made to theme files.

Ask the googles/bings/ducks about Child Themes (there are plugins that will create one for you), and also about Templates and how they work. Some programming skills are needed to understand how templates work.

Comment: Hi thanks for the insights. Yes it is a child theme. Can you have a look at the screenshots I just uploaded and it might help explain my mess a bit more